# Excel Function To Convert English Names To Arabic

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a VBA function to my excel sheet were I can translate or convert the names to arabic to stop them in my database. I added the developer tab and open editor and I added the following function but it is not working...Any help please

```
Function Translate_To_Arabic(str) As String
' Tools Refrence Select Microsoft internet Control


    Dim IE As Object, i As Long
    Dim inputstring As String, outputstring As String, text_to_convert As String, result_data As String, CLEAN_DATA

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    '   TO CHOOSE INPUT LANGUAGE

    inputstring = "auto"

    '   TO CHOOSE OUTPUT LANGUAGE

    outputstring = "ar"

    text_to_convert = str

    'open website

    IE.Visible = False
    IE.navigate "http://translate.google.com/#" & inputstring & "/" & outputstring & "/" & text_to_convert

    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5"))

    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    CLEAN_DATA = Split(Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(IE.Document.getElementById("result_box").innerHTML, "</SPAN>", ""), "<")

    For j = LBound(CLEAN_DATA) To UBound(CLEAN_DATA)
        result_data = result_data & Right(CLEAN_DATA(j), Len(CLEAN_DATA(j)) - InStr(CLEAN_DATA(j), ">"))
    Next


    IE.Quit
    transalte_using_vba = result_data


End Function
```

Comment: the first part of the last line `transalte_using_vba` must be the same as your function name. for example if you change the function name to `somefunction` then you must change the last line to `somefunction = result_data`.

Comment: I tried this but still not working.... I am opening the editor inserting a new module that saving it as an add-in.xlam and then I'm adding it...but still not working

Comment: see my answer. this will work in your workbook , but note this function is very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your last line of the code should be:

```
Translate_To_Arabic = result_data
```

You have mispeeled "Translate"

Also make sure you added the Reference to the Microsoft Internet Controls

Comment: psssst. you misspelled `mispeeled`

Comment: What is it that isn't working. Are you getting an error pop up? Is the result of the formula `#NAME` or `#REF` or `#N/A` or NULL. Is the UDF just not running? I tried your function as-is (after correcting the spelling) by placing the function in a new module, saving the worksheet, and then entering `=Translate_To_Arabic("Test")` into a cell and it came back as Arabic. I can't read Arabic, but I assume it said "Test".

Answer (score 0):

If You want to use this function as UDF use this code:

```
Function Translate_To_Arabic(Rng As Range) As String
' Tools Refrence Select Microsoft internet Control


    Dim IE As Object, i As Long
    Dim inputstring As String, outputstring As String, text_to_convert As String, result_data As String, CLEAN_DATA

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    '   TO CHOOSE INPUT LANGUAGE

    inputstring = "auto"

    '   TO CHOOSE OUTPUT LANGUAGE

    outputstring = "ar"

    text_to_convert = Rng.Text

    'open website

    IE.Visible = False
    IE.navigate "http://translate.google.com/#" & inputstring & "/" & outputstring & "/" & text_to_convert

    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5"))

    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    CLEAN_DATA = Split(Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(IE.Document.getElementById("result_box").innerHTML, "</SPAN>", ""), "<")

    For j = LBound(CLEAN_DATA) To UBound(CLEAN_DATA)
        result_data = result_data & Right(CLEAN_DATA(j), Len(CLEAN_DATA(j)) - InStr(CLEAN_DATA(j), ">"))
    Next


    IE.Quit
    Translate_To_Arabic = result_data


End Function
```

you can use this function in your workbook using this formula in B1: `=Translate_To_Arabic(A1)`. now if you type `book` in cell A1 you will see `كتاب` in cell B1.
if you want to use this function as add-in see [this link](http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut03.htm)