# Excel Function To Convert Arabic Names To English

Tags: excel, encoding, user-defined-functions, translate, large-data

Through this link [[Excel Function To Convert English Names To Arabic]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34776110/excel-function-to-convert-english-names-to-arabic#) I tried to adapt the following code to translate names from Arabic To English

```
Function Translate_To_English (Rng As Range) As String
' Tools Refrence Select Microsoft internet Control


    Dim IE As Object, i As Long
    Dim inputstring As String, outputstring As String, text_to_convert As String, result_data As String, CLEAN_DATA

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    '   TO CHOOSE INPUT LANGUAGE

    inputstring = "ar"

    '   TO CHOOSE OUTPUT LANGUAGE

    outputstring = "en"

    text_to_convert = Rng.Text

    'open website

    IE.Visible = False
    IE.navigate "http://translate.google.com/#" & inputstring & "/" & outputstring & "/" & text_to_convert

    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5"))

    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    CLEAN_DATA = Split(Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(IE.Document.getElementById("result_box").innerHTML, "</SPAN>", ""), "<")

    For j = LBound(CLEAN_DATA) To UBound(CLEAN_DATA)
        result_data = result_data & Right(CLEAN_DATA(j), Len(CLEAN_DATA(j)) - InStr(CLEAN_DATA(j), ">"))
    Next


    IE.Quit
    Translate_To_English = result_data
End Function`
```

but it didn't work and says error

[this is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPXu9.png)

Any help, please?

Comment: "...it didn't work". How doesn't it work? Is there an error thrown somewhere (if so, what error, where)? Does it run, but nothing happens? Does it run but get incorrect translations? ...etc.

Comment: Google translate has an API you can use instead of an IE object.

Comment: why would you do it using that, it's not efficient, how about using mapping character method through db  ?

Answer (score 0):

I just got a code for linking Google translate with Google sheets.

```
=GOOGLETRANSLATE(C4, "ar", "en")
```

It works but it sometimes gives the meaning of the names and the result becomes so funny.

For instance:

Ali Saleh's patience    علي صالح صبر

Ali Hussein is boring   علي حسين غثيث

The age of the present age  عمر حاضر عمر